# ActiveRecord query to load models, and conditionally their children

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Question` model and an `Answer` model. `Answer` `belongs_to` `Question` and has a `date` column.

I'm making a "answers for a given date" page. I'm trying to display all the `Question`s, and for each of them display any answers they have where "answers"."date" is the given date.

#### What I've tried

```rb
    @questions = Question.includes(:answers).
                          where('answers.date = ?', params[:date]).
                          references(:answers)
```

When I do this, it doesn't load the questions that don't have any answers for that date. Same if I replace `includes` with `left_joins`.

#### My working (but inefficient) solution

Get all the questions, and get all the answers for the desired day

```rb
    @questions = Question.all.to_a
    @answers = Answer.where(date: params[:date]).to_a
```

Then for each question, I search the `@answers` array

```rb
@questions.each do |question|
  current_answers = @answers.select { |a| a.question_id == question.id }
  # render stuff
end
```

Since I'm never going to have more than a few hundred questions, I'm not super concerned about this solution, but I'd like a more elegant option than searching through an array over and over.

Answer (score 0):

If You need to display all of the questions, I don't think you need to add

```
where('answers.date = ?', params[:date])
```

in your code, since it won't load the questions that don't have any answers for that date.

---

For displaying the answer, I think you could do something like this

```
@questions.first.answers.where(date: params[:date]).first
```

Comment: Won't applying that `where` make it do another query to the database?

Comment: Because we already eager loading the relation, I think it won't do another query